# JSONArray java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I'm using JSONObject to parse the JSON file and get its contents. Everything goes fine but tags aren't showing in the RecyclerView.

Here's the code :

```
private void direct_url(){
    v_title = findViewById(R.id.vid_title);
    String url = kw_url_holder.getText().toString();
    String server_tag_url = "https://server.com/json.json";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, server_tag_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                String title,views,likes,dislikes,publishedon,duration;
                JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                title = object.getString("title");
                v_title.setText(title);
                JSONArray tagsJsonArray = object.getJSONArray("tags");
                for(int i=0; i<tagsJsonArray.length();i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject tagObj = new JSONObject();
                        tagObj = tagsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        TagUrlResultsModel tagUrlResultsModel = new TagUrlResultsModel();
                        tagUrlResultsModel.setV_tags(tagObj.getString(String.valueOf(i)));
                        url_result.add(tagUrlResultsModel);
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error",error.toString());
        }
    });
    url_queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(tags.this);
    url_queue.add(request);
}
```

The JSON:

```
{
    "title": "The Title",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}
```

An error in the logs:

> Error: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: `JSONObject object=new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));`

Comment: at first show us whats `response` return

Comment: I didn't know what you mean by "response"? I' fetching the given JSON file from the server and trying to parse tags into RecyclerView

Comment: I've pasted the entire function that I'm using. [Question Updated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside your for loop in:

```
JSONObject tagObj = new JSONObject();
tagObj = tagsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
TagUrlResultsModel tagUrlResultsModel = new TagUrlResultsModel();
tagUrlResultsModel.setV_tags(tagObj.getString(String.valueOf(i)));
url_result.add(tagUrlResultsModel);
```

It should be

```
String tag;
tag = tagsJsonArray.getString(i);
TagUrlResultsModel tagUrlResultsModel = new TagUrlResultsModel();
tagUrlResultsModel.setV_tags(tag);
url_result.add(tagUrlResultsModel);
```

Using `getString()` instead of `getJSONObject()` as the content of that JSONArray is just strings.

That's why you are getting in that catch:

> Error: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I've done this but tags aren't displayed in the RecyclerView.                             String tag;
                            tag = tagsJsonArray.getString(i);
                            TagUrlResultsModel tagUrlResultsModel = new TagUrlResultsModel();
                            tagUrlResultsModel.setV_tags(String.valueOf(i));
                            url_result.add(tagUrlResultsModel);

Comment: It should be `setV_tags(tag)` with that change as tag contains the string itself, check the updated answer

Comment: Still not showing, it's unusual as it says No adapter attached; skipping layout. However, I've set the adapter

Comment: Then you are likely to have another bug on the RecyclerView adapter, which is not in the question

Comment: I've checked the Logs, all the tags are fetched by the code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help